# Math.Random equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, random

I have been programming in Java for three years, and have been using Math.random() to get a random number. I'm fairly new to C++, and I was wondering if there was equivalent to that but in C++? A specific function or method that I could use? Also include an explanation. Thanks so much!

Comment: What does Math.random do?

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+random&oq=c%2B%2B+random&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2151j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) are some relevant search results. The query was "c++ random"

Comment: You can read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for pseudo-random number generation.

Comment: maybe rand() is a good function.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson or maybe the `random` header which is included in C++11 STL.

Answer (score 4):

C++ provides a fairly nice random number library, `<random>`, but it doesn't yet have the sort of dead simple API beginners generally want. It's easy to produce such an API, as I show below, and hopefully some such API will be included at some point.

The C++ API splits random number generation into two parts, sources of 'randomness', and machinery for turning randomness into numbers with specific distributions. Many basic uses of random numbers don't particularly care how good (or fast, or small) the source of 'randomness' is, and they only need 'uniform' distributions. So the typically recommended source of randomness is the "Mersenne Twister" engine. You create one of these and seed it like so:

```
#include <random>

int main() {
  std::mt19937 eng{42};
}
```

Now `eng` is an object that can be passed around and used as a source for random bits. It's a value-type so you can make copies of it, assign to it, etc. like a normal value. In terms of thread safety, accessing this value is like accessing any other, so if you need multiple threads you should either put an engine on each thread or use mutual exclusion.

To turn data from an engine into random values, use a distribution object. Typical uses need 'uniform' distributions, so for integral values use `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>`.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dice{1, 6};
```

A distribution object is a function object, and you get values from it by calling it and passing it the source of randomness it will use:

```
auto die_roll = dice(eng);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the math for producing random values should be encapsulated inside a distribution object. If you find yourself doing some kind of transformation on the results then you probably should be using a different distribution. Don't do things like `dist(eng) % 10` or `dist(eng) / 6.0 + 10.0`. There are several other distributions provided in the library, including ones for producing floating point values with various distributions.

Here's a pretty easy way to wrap the `<random>` functionality for simple usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

std::mt19937 seeded_eng() {
  std::random_device r;
  std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
  return std::mt19937(seed);
}

class Random {
  std::mt19937 eng = seeded_eng();
public:
  auto operator()(int a, int b) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(a, b);
    return dist(eng);
  }
};

int main() {
  Random random;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Dice: " << random(1, 6) << " " << random(1, 6) << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int) time (NULL)); //activates the generator
    //...
    int a = rand()%10;        //gives a random from 0 to 9

    double r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));        //gives a random from 0 to 1

    int max, min;
    //...
    int c = (rand()%(max - min)) + min;              //gives a random from min to max
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

These ways are the simpliest. 
Sometimes it means "the best", sometimes - not.

Comment: Using modulo with `rand` defeats the purpose as explained here: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Comment: @Brandon, uniform distribution is _irrelevant_ for the vast majority of use cases. The sort of people who worry about that are the sort of people who wouldn't be caught dead using a linear congruential method in the first place. You may want to read the second aparagraph of the conclusion for that link you gave.

Comment: I wasn't intending to imply that it should never be done. I was just adding more information to the responses for future readers. It was not something anyone explained to me when I first began desiring the usage of random numbers and had I known this information I would have definitely preferred alternatives to it so here I am providing that for other newcomers that may not know this information yet.

Answer (score 0):

1.srand((unsigned) time(0)) will make sure that everytime you run your program that the rand() function will get a new seed causing it to produce a different or "random" output. Without stand((unsigned) time(0)), the rand() will produce the same output.

2.int Number, is used to store the random number that is being generated by the rand() function. The rand() % 27 will give you numbers 0-26.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0))
    int Number = ((rand() % 27));
    cout << Number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. The function random is overloaded. One instance is used to acquire a random number generator for integers. Another instance is used to acquire a random number generator for doubles. After you have these two functions, applications becomes rather trivial as can be observed in the main function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>

// Single global engine, a better version of std::rand
std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device()() };

// Returns a generator producing uniform random integers in the closed range [a, b]
std::function<int()> random(int a, int b)
{
    auto dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(a, b);

    return std::bind(dist, std::ref(engine));
}

// Returns a generator producing uniform random doubles in the half-open range [x, y)
std::function<double()> random(double x, double y)
{
    auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(x, y);

    return std::bind(dist, std::ref(engine));
}

int main()
{
    const auto no_iterations = int{ 12 };

    auto dice = random(1, 6);

    // Roll the dice a few times and observe the outcome
    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
        no_iterations, dice);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // U is a uniform random variable on the unit interval [0, 1]
    auto U = random(0.0, 1.0);

    // Generate some observations
    std::vector<double> observations;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(observations), no_iterations, U);

    // Calculate the mean of the observations
    auto sum = std::accumulate(observations.cbegin(), observations.cend(), 0.0);
    auto mean = sum / no_iterations;
    std::cout << "The mean is " << mean << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```